# Azure Data Factory - Tumbling Window Trigger - Limit hours it is running

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

With an Azure Data Factory "Tumbling Window" trigger, is it possible to limit the hours of each day that it triggers during (adding a window you might say)?

For example I have a Tumbling Window trigger that runs a pipeline every 15 minutes. This is currently running 24/7 but I'd like it to only run during business hours (0700-1900) to reduce costs.

**Edit:**

I played around with this, and found another option which isn't ideal from a monitoring perspective, but it appears to work:

Create a new pipeline with a single "If Condition" step with a dynamic Expression like this:

`@and(greater(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')),6),less(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')),20))`

- In the true case activity, add an Execute Pipeline step executing your original pipeline (with "Wait on completion" ticked)
- In the false case activity, add a wait step which sleeps for X minutes

The longer you sleep for, the longer you can possibly encroach on your window, so adjust that to match.

I need to give it a couple of days before I check the billing on the portal to see if it has reduced costs. At the moment I'm assuming a job which just sleeps for 15 minutes won't incur the costs that one running and processing data would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the Advanced recurrency options present in the schedule type trigger.

[image: ADF trigger advanced recurrence options]

Answer (score 0):

there is no easy way but you can create two deployment pipelines for the same job in Azure devops and as soon as your winodw 0700 to 1900 expires you replace that job with a dummy job using azure dev ops pipeline.